# Append Image if child element doesnt exist replace if it does exist

Tags: javascript, replace, append

I have this code that appends an image to a centercol element

```
  var largeImage = document.createElement('img');
  largeImage.id = 'largeImage'; 

   var newNode = document.querySelector('#centercol');
   newNode.appendChild(LargeImage);
```

However I want to replace the appended element if it already exists

I require an if else statement ; here's an example of my logic

```
   if  {
  while(newNode.hasChildNodes()) newNode.removeChild(newNode.lastChild); //remove child nodes

  } else { 
   newNode.appendChild(largeImage) ;
```

Comment: Just check if `largeImage` exists, and if it does remove it, ID's are unique so there's only one such element.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, **[here 4 examples](http://jsfiddle.net/WN87S/)**, using:

1) Replacing the *src* property of the image:

```
i.src=C.g();
```

2) Using *replaceChild* with the parent (note: you must pass first the new, then the old):

```
i.parentNode.replaceChild(n,i);
```

3) Replacing parent's *innerHTML*. This overwrites any child, but can add more elements at once:

```
i.parentNode.innerHTML='<img src="...">';
```

4) Preload: Creates the image and uses *onload* event to *replaceChild*.

```
n.onload=
 function(e)
  {
   i.parentNode.replaceChild(e.target,i);
   i=e.target;
  };
```